# How to push elements into array in react state, the array is located inside of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, javascript-objects, use-state

Push object inside of questions array in data, it gives this errors
Uncaught TypeError: data.sections is not iterable
at handleClick (SecondStep.tsx:14:1)

```js
export default function CreateStepper() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: "",
    desc: "",
    sections: [],
  });

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <><SecondStep data={data} setData={setData} /></>)
}


function SecondStep(data: any, setData: any) {
  const [addSection, setAddSection] = useState(1);
  const newSection = {
    sectionName: "Hdsd",
    sectionDesc: "dsdsd",
    question: [],
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setData({ ...data, sections: [...data.sections, newSection] });
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      
    </Box>
  );
}

export default SecondStep;
```

When I did below code it retuns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')" this type error. How to push new object to the array in React useState. First of all, useState is object inside the object it has questions: [] array how to push the object this array

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: "",
    desc: "",
    sections: [],
 });

const newSection = {
    sectionName: "Hello",
    sectionDesc: "Desc",
    question: [],
};

const handleClick = () => {
   let copyData = data;
   copyData.sections.push(newSection);
   setData(copyData);
 };
```

Comment: The problem is that you are declaring the setDate inside another function. That's why it does not work.

Comment: Sorry for my explanation. How to fix this issue

Comment: Yes I will create a Solution one Moment.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the latest version of the state in the setState Method, where you then can add your object.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: "",
    desc: "",
    sections: [],
 });

const newSection = {
    sectionName: "Hello",
    sectionDesc: "Desc",
    question: [],
};

const handleClick = () => {
   setData(data => ({
     ...data,
     sections: [...data.sections, newSection]
   })
 };
```

But I am actually not quite sure if you need the `...data` you might be able to leave that out.

Comment: it gives error: "TypeError: setData is not a function"

Comment: doing this is same in typescript

Comment: Which version of React are you using ?

Comment: React version 18.2.0 in package.json

Comment: Hi, like @AppyMango also created the Sandbox you can see in my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-haze-qrpgy2?file=/src/App.tsx that it is infact workling with this code.

Comment: If there still are Issues with your code these are not related to this problem. To solve these please provide the complete file you are using this in, because there might be other Problems.

Answer (score 2):

You have to clone the object and then push the elements into the array,

here is the example below,

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, {useState} from 'react'

export default function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: "",
    desc: "",
    sections: [],
 });

const newSection = {
    sectionName: "Hello",
    sectionDesc: "Desc",
    question: [],
};

const handleClick = () => {
   setData({...data, sections:[...data.sections, newSection]});
 };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
      <h4>Sections: {data.sections[0]?.sectionName}</h4>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-do7bk?file=/src/App.js:0-572

Comment: It gives error: "Uncaught TypeError: data.sections is not iterable" this thing is same in TypeScript

Comment: Can you post the latest code? so we can look at whats happening.

Comment: in this question, or create seperate question

Comment: I have updated the code ? can you check it

Answer (score 1):

The answer to you Updated Problem is:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const CreateStepper = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: "",
    desc: "",
    sections: []
  });

  const SecondStep = (data: any) => {
    const [addSection, setAddSection] = useState(1);
    const newSection = {
      sectionName: "Hdsd",
      sectionDesc: "dsdsd",
      question: []
    };

    const handleClick = () => {
      setData({ ...data, sections: [...data.sections, newSection] });
    };

    return <></>;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SecondStep data={data} />
    </>
  );
};

export default CreateStepper;
```

You could also provide SecondStep with the function via the Props If you prefer That this should work to:

```js
export default function CreateStepper() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: "",
    desc: "",
    sections: [],
  });

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <><SecondStep data={data} setData={setData} /></>)
}


function SecondStep(data: any, setData: (data : any) => void) {
  const [addSection, setAddSection] = useState(1);
  const newSection = {
    sectionName: "Hdsd",
    sectionDesc: "dsdsd",
    question: [],
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    props.setData({ ...data, sections: [...data.sections, newSection] });
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      
    </Box>
  );
}

export default SecondStep;
```

Comment: Then feel free to accept my answer so other people know what helped you.